# Change visual indentation in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a option or plugin for vscode that allows to stretch current indentation to make it more readable **without** changing `n` tabs/spaces setting of project/global?

[image]

Comment: You could try Allman style instead, where the opening brace is on its own line. I couldn't find a name for the style you appear to actually want on the Wikipedia [Indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) page, so maybe you'll need to write your own formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation the only way I found working is that if you format your repository with tabs, user can set preferable (visual only for him) `tab size` in vscode not affecting others users or repository.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

i never seen such a plugin but you could try indent rainbow [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB4XB.png)
i personally use and it made readability much better